# Env variables in data class in Redis model annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, model

Troubling to specify dynamic env variable in the model class @Hashkey Redis annotation.

Model:

```
@RedisHash("${spring.redis.namespace}:Book")
public class Book {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

My application.properties file:

```
spring.redis.namespace=local
```

The resulting key is "${spring.redis.namespace}:Book" instead of local:Book

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use [Keyspaces](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#redis.repositories.keyspaces) to do it. There two ways. I use one way to finish your requirement.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories(keyspaceConfiguration = MyKeyspaceConfiguration.class)
public class ApplicationConfig {

  @Value("${spring.redis.namespace}:Book")
  String myKey;

  //... RedisConnectionFactory and RedisTemplate Bean definitions omitted

  public static class MyKeyspaceConfiguration extends KeyspaceConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected Iterable<KeyspaceSettings> initialConfiguration() {
      return Collections.singleton(new KeyspaceSettings(Book.class, myKey));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove value from @RedisHash annotation

```
@RedisHash
public class Book {}
```

and then define keyspaces

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RedisConfig {

  private static String staticBookKeyspace;

  @Value("${spring.redis.namespace}:Book")
  public void setBookKeyspaceStatic(String name){
      RedisConfig.staticBookKeyspace = name;
  }

  @Bean
  public RedisMappingContext keyValueMappingContext() {
    return new RedisMappingContext(
          new MappingConfiguration(new IndexConfiguration(), new MyKeyspaceConfiguration()));
  }

  public static class MyKeyspaceConfiguration extends KeyspaceConfiguration {
    @Override
    protected Iterable<KeyspaceSettings> initialConfiguration() {
        return Collections.singleton(new KeyspaceSettings(Book.class, staticBookKeyspace));
    }
  }
}
```